# tabcontroller does not change when scrolling the screen(like its waiting 1 sec). tabtext is changing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tabbar below like Tab (text: '') and _tabcontroller, 
if i use tab.text for body its working good (body:Text(tab.text)) but if i create a list for index's and use exampleList[_tabcontroller.index] its chancing slow like i am swiping screen and it wait 1 sec. My code is larger than i posted but its my core problem i think.
n: i wanna use Tab's like Tab(child:Row()) so i cant use tab.text if it have alternative i will be ok too(idk tab.listener or tab.id? )

```
    TabController _tabController;
    final List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[
new Tab(text: "hello1",),
new Tab(text:"hello2"),

  ];
...
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_tabController = new TabController(
    vsync: this, length: tabs.length, initialIndex: cDate);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleSelected);

}
void _handleSelected() {
setState(() {
  _tabController.index;
});
}
@override
void dispose() {
_tabController.dispose();
super.dispose();
 }
...
    body: new TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: tabs.map((Tab tab) {
     //ITS FAST BUT I DONT WANNA USE LIKE THAT:
      return Center(Text(tab.text));
    //ITS SLOW BUT I WANNA USE LIKE THAT:
      return Center(Text(etcList[_tabcontroller.index] );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

tried to explain but my english is not good sorry

Comment: What does `setState(() {
  _tabController.index;
});` do?

Comment: _myHandler = _tabs[tabController.index]; in there but it does mather ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's happening because of `TabBarView` is animating between the tabs and `_tabController.index` value is only changed once the animation is complete.

Here I am using `_tabController.index` value to get the object of `Choice` form list `choices` and showing that as the `title` in `AppBar`.

```
  appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(choices[_tabController.index].title),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
```

**ISSUE**

[image: issue_gif]

**SOLUTION**

[image]

As `TabBarView` is animating the between tabs,One can add a listener to `_tabController`'s animation.

```
_tabController.animation
  ..addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = (_tabController.animation.value).round(); //_tabController.animation.value returns double
      print('_tabController.animation.value: ${_tabController.animation.value}');
      print('_currentIndex: $_currentIndex');
    });
  });
```

**Here is full code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleTabScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SampleTabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleTabScreenState createState() => _SampleTabScreenState();
}

class _SampleTabScreenState extends State<SampleTabScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
    _tabController.animation
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = (_tabController.animation.value).round(); //_tabController.animation.value returns double
          print('_tabController.animation.value: ${_tabController.animation.value}');
          print('_currentIndex: $_currentIndex');
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(choices[_currentIndex].title),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'CAR', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'BICYCLE', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'BOAT', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'BUS', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'TRAIN', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'WALK', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is also good use `value = _tabController.animation.value.round()` and `if (value != _currentIndex) setState(() => _currentIndex = value);` to avoid calling `setState()` multiple times.